Modelling quantum harmonic oscillator for oscillations of simple linear molecules (IR spectroscopy)
My question is how to model the oscillation of atoms in simple molecules (for instance $Cl_2$ or other gases) when exited by infrared photons.
I mean how to get theoretically their IR spectrum approximating it to a simple quantum harmonic oscillator. I'm learning about it on Griffiths QM and I read on my chemistry book that such molecules are described by it. But instead of the mass in the $\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}$ formula there's a $\mu$ instead of the mass that is a function of the masses of the other two molecules. How does it work?

Closely related and maybe a duplicate: Energy of molecular vibrations.
